# Fastest algorithm for primality test

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, primes

I need to test primality on intervals between numbers which are really big (in the range of long long), so i need some fast algorithm for checking if a number is prime or not. Please suggest your ideas.

Comment: Do you only need to check if it is prime, or do you need to find its prime factors?

Comment: Prime factorization is difficult. That's what RSA encryption is based on. Though you did not answer Stephen's question so I a assume you just want to test a number for primality.

Comment: Dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/627463/how-can-i-test-for-primality

Comment: Do you need to know for sure whether it's a prime or not, or would you be satisfied with having a very high probability of the right answer?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about number theory. Try math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 19):

One good method is the [Miller-Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) test. It should be noted however, that this is only a probabilistic test.

Comment: Miller-Rabin can be adapted to be deterministic under the assumption of the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis. Since the GRH is widely believed to true I could envision a scenario where you were using this test as though it were proven deterministic since it is by far the fastest.

Comment: @Mark: and for the specified range of inputs, we don't need to assume GRH is true, we only need a weaker assumption that the deterministic version of M-R has no false positives below LONGLONG_MAX. This is probably easier to prove, although I still wouldn't fancy trying to do so by exhaustive test.

Answer (score 18):

A Miller-Rabin test to the seven bases 2, 325, 9375, 28178, 450775, 9780504, 1795265022 has been proved by Jim Sinclair to deterministically test if a number less than 2^64 is prime. See http://miller-rabin.appspot.com/.

Answer (score 10):

I believe that the asymptotically fastest current (non-probabilistic) primality test is the "Lenstra/Pomerance improved AKS", which has complexity that is essentially O(n^6).

However, the range of `long long` (assuming a typical system where that is a 64 bit integer) is not really that big.  In particular, there are only ~200 million primes less than 2^32, so using a fast probabilistic test, followed by trial division with a precomputed list of primes (or just looking the number up in a list of primes, if you have one) would be pretty darn fast in that range, and is probably the right way to go about it.

Comment: You don't need to do trial division after the probabilistic test. If you run the probabilist test n iterations then the probability of an incorrect answer is 1/2^n so if n = 100 the algorithm would be incorrect 1 in 10^30 times. It is better to just run the probabilistic test more iterations than doing trial division.

Comment: In particular, on real hardware you rapidly reach the point where the probabilistic test's chance of failure is no worse than a deterministic test's chance of failure due to register values being flipped by unusually energetic cosmic rays (or other sporadic hardware fault).

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest the [GNU MP library](http://gmplib.org/manual/Number-Theoretic-Functions.html#Number-Theoretic-Functions) that uses the [Miller-Rabin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) algorithm. I have used it for a few months and it's very fast.

Specifically, the function mpz_probab_prime_p does this, you can also use another function mpz_nextprime to find the next prime number greater than a number. I can post code samples if you would like.

Answer (score 6):

I came up with a really good algorithm, that is much faster than checking all the divisors - which of course also lets me crack public key encryption.

Hang on - I just need to close the window, there are all these black helicopters overhead ........

(Or look at [How can I test for primality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/627463/how-can-i-test-for-primality))

Comment: Factorizing composite numbers (which would be needed to crack RSA) is different from just testing if a number is prime (which doesn't necessarily require to find any specific factors). In fact implementing RSA requires to find primes with hundreds of digits, which would be unfeasible with a simple "check all potential divisors" algorithm.

Comment: Yes but if there were a faster method of testing primes, you wouldn't be telling anybody about it here ;-)   The question was goign to get closed as dupe anyway.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to test a long long for primality then the [Baillie PSW primality test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baillie%E2%80%93PSW_primality_test) is a good choice. This test does one strong pseudoprime test and one Lucas test and hence is very fast. It is expected that there exist some composites that pass this test, but so far none are known, and there certainly is no exception below 10<sup>15</sup>. A variant of this test is for example used in Mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

Cobbal and grokus are right.  The Miller-Rabin test is the most useful of the available algorithms.  Yes, it is probabilistic, but really shouldn't scare you off.  The test is the most widely used for practical purposes.

Note that the probability of false positives (there are no false negatives) can be made arbitrarily small by repeating the test.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at my answer here:

[how to test a prime number 1000 digits long?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282271/how-to-test-a-prime-number-1000-digits-long/1282397#1282397)

The test is very fast. If you are working in the 64-bit or smaller range, you can throw in a GCD with 30030 to save a bit of time for the majority of numbers.

Answer (score -1):

The best algorithm best of my view is "ALI primality test".

Answer (score -3):

Fastest would probably be to look it up in a precomputed list of primes. See [here for example](http://primes.utm.edu/), they have up to 2^43112609-1 (largest known prime).

Comment: This would not work.  No computer has ever had enough storage to hold a list this long.  The list would require more than a billion gigabytes of storage without compression, based on a rough estimate for `pi(2^64)`.

Comment: @Dietrich: But OP doesn't need that many.